# filtering nested objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, nested-object

I have the following nested objects in javascript and I would like to filter based on a specific condition (value < 7). How can I do this in JS?

Input:

```
const data = [
{key: 'a', value: [{key: 'aa', value: 6}, {key: 'ab', value: 10}]},
{key: 'b', value: [{key: 'ba', value: 3}, {key: 'bb', value: 11}]}
]
```

Expected output:

```
const data = [
{key: 'a', value: [{key: 'aa', value: 6}]},
{key: 'b', value: [{key: 'ba', value: 3}]}
]
```

I have tried already some and filter but it is not working as expected.

Thanks!

Comment: map and do a filter inside for value and returned the filtered value

Comment: "I have tried already some and filter but it is not working as expected." please share that attempt as an [edit] to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you can use arrow functions:

```js
const filteredData = data.map(item => {
  item.value = item.value.filter(subItem => subItem.value < 7);
  return item;
});
```

And if you're working in an environment where you can use the spread operator:

```js
const filteredData = data.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  value: item.value.filter(subItem => subItem.value < 7),
}));
```

Comment: Often it is recommended not to use `map` with side effects, but rather use `forEach` or a conventional loop.

Comment: Yeah, fair, depends if you care about keeping the original data intact I guess. Also makes the 2nd option preferable.

Comment: Yes the 2nd option is nice, especially if you need the immutability

Comment: Agree with Berthur. The top code _makes it look like_ you're only returning a new structure, but you're also mutating the original structure in the process. That's a subtle bug waiting to ruin someone's day. Suggest removal/conversion to `forEach` with no return value.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive function, without touching the original object

```js
const data = [
  {key: 'a', value: [{key: 'aa', value: 6}, {key: 'ab', value: 10}]},
  {key: 'b', value: [{key: 'ba', value: 3}, {key: 'bb', value: 11}]}
];
const filterData = (dataOriginal, minValue) => {
  //INFO: create copy of the object
  const d = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataOriginal));
  //-----
  return d.filter((item,i) => {
    if(typeof item.value === 'number'){
      return item.value < minValue;
    } else if(Array.isArray(item.value)) {
      const f = filterData(item.value, minValue);
      d[i].value = f;
      return !!f.length;
    }
  });
};

const filtered = filterData(data, 7);
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, but how about e.g. this:

```
for (const o of data) o.value = o.value.filter(e => e.value < 7);
```

Comment: `for (o of data)` creates a global variable `o`. Always use `const` or `let` (if you plan to reassign the var, which you normally shouldn't). Best style is to use `{}` on `for` loop blocks as well.

Comment: @ggorlen `const`: my bad, it slipped me, thanks. As for `{}`, that's really down to style and individual preference. I find that sometimes, especially when working with lots of similar low-level code, omitting `{}` in if statements and for loops can make the code more concise and readable.